# Can I free() something in C that has been malloc()'ed in C++?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, language-lawyer, free

I'm writing a wrapper for a library written in C++, such that it can be used from C. In the wrapper code I'm making lots of copies of the underlying data of c++ containers. E.g. if the c++ library function returns a `std::vector<int>`, my wrapper will return a struct of the form `{size_t len; size_t size; void *arr;}`, where `arr` contains a copy of the data from the vector. When the user is done with the data, they must free it.

My question is: is it *always* legal for the user (C-code) to call `free()` on pointers which have been `malloc()`:d in C++? Or must I create an equivalent function in my wrapper code?

Comment: You may not assume that C++ memory allocation is done via the same mechanism as `malloc`/`free`. However, if you created the copy of the vector using `malloc` from C++, you may `free` it from C.

Comment: Your interface should be symmetric: if the library provides a function or mechanism that results in an allocation, the library should _also_ provide a function or mechanism that frees that memory. The caller has no business in manually freeing memory allocated by your library.

Comment: @paddy: it is not uncommon in C language to return a pointer to a block of memory that the caller should free after use. You have to provide explicit close or clean functions when other operations are required before free-ing the memory bloc. That being said, always providing those functions is a guarantee to not break the interface contract if you need such operations in a later version and because of that is a *best practice*.

Comment: The (usuallly) safest and most flexible solution is to write a "proper" abstraction layer with a fully opaque type and accessor/mutator functions.

Comment: But the core problem is bad design of those libraries and not that correctly designing a library freeing its own memory is mission impossible. It's pretty simple really - just provide a clean-up function as part of the API.

Comment: The answer in general is "it depends" different parts of the program could be using different heaps and calling `free` from one heap for memory allocated by a different one will lead to an error. Nothing to do with using c or c++ though

Comment: Different libraries can have different heaps. Also, different parts of your code may straight up link against different malloc implementations. There are plenty of questions touching on that subject, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649739/when-exactly-would-a-dll-use-a-different-heap-than-the-executable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928431/c-interface-design-around-shared-library-boundaries/6932010#6932010

Comment: In most (if not all) cases you should avoid that, because `free()` may violate basic RAII stuff like calling destructors. A reasonable option would be to have an `extern "C"` exposed function for deletion, which would be in C++ and call `delete` (or whatever the library API expects to be called) right there in C++. This pattern is not uncommon even in pure C APIs. Consider `freeaddrinfo()`, for example. One could probably call `free()` on the result from `getaddrinfo()`, but it would leak the rest of the linked list.

Comment: That's what `std::malloc` and `std::free` are *for*. Why would anyone need them otherwise?

Comment: The real issue here is that you shouldn't be calling `malloc()` in the first place in C++. You should be using `new`: and `delete`, or `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: @user207421 Why is that an issue, apart from being (subjectively) poor taste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You can mix C++'s `std::malloc` and C's `free`

`std::malloc` in C++ is defined in `<cstdlib>` which is said to have the same contents and meaning as `<stdlib.h>` in C (with some variations, such as namespacing). Furthermore, [[c.malloc]](https://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc) says:

> ```cpp
> void* aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);
> void* calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
> void* malloc(size_t size);
> void* realloc(void* ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: These functions have the semantics specified in the C standard library.

This means that you can allocate some memory with `std::malloc` in C++ an pass it to some C function which calls `free`.

---

*Note: mixing different standard libraries or mixing different builds (debug/release) of the same standard library might still be an issue, but that applies to all language features.*

#### The C++ standard library doesn't use `std::malloc`

That being said, it would not be safe to use `free` for memory allocated by something like a `std::vector` like you've suggested.
All containers which do some memory allocation use `std::allocator` by default, which uses `operator new`.

Mixing `new` and `free` would be undefined behavior, even if the underlying OS functions to obtain and release memory are the same.

#### How to use `std::vector` in C

```c
// C23
struct vector {
    // note: 3 pointers in size is usually the bare minimum which is needed for
    //       a std::vector.
    alignas(void*) unsigned char data[3 * sizeof(void*)];
};

// Note the symmetric interface; it doesn't matter how init/destroy are
// implemented to the user.
void vector_init(struct vector*);
void vector_destroy(struct vector*);
// Also add this and other functions to make the vector useful.
void vector_push(struct vector*, int element);

int main() {
    vector v;
    vector_init(&v); // no malloc, no free
    vector_push(&v, 42);
    vector_destroy(&v);
}
```

So far, we've basically just defined a `struct vector` to contain some amount of bytes, and three opaque functions. All the code is C23-compatible, and we could implement the actual functionality in C++.

```cpp
// C++20
static_assert(alignof(vector::data) >= alignof(std::vector));
static_assert(sizeof(vector::data) >= sizeof(std::vector));

extern "C" void vector_init(vector* v) {
    std::construct_at(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(v->data));
}

extern "C" void vector_destroy(vector* v) {
    std::destroy_at(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(v->data));
}

extern "C" void vector_push(vector* v, int element) {
    auto* vec = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(v->data));
    vec->push_back(element);
}
```

The C++ side uses `std::construct_at` (or prior to C++20, you could use placement new). We create a `std::vector` in the raw bytes of `vector::data`.
Note that we aren't calling `new`, `delete`, `malloc`, or `free` anywhere in this code.
`std::vector` is still responsible for all the memory management.

Comment: I think saying that it's fine is misleading. The question asks if it's _always_ okay, and the truth is that it's not unless you're compiling _all_ applicable libraries against the same standard library. What's far more likely, given OP is writing a wrapper, is that they are starting with a compiled binary that has a C++ interface. The problem here is that the wrapper can potentially link against a different standard library (_e.g._ debugging on/off, address sanitizer) and then all hell potentially breaks loose when the wrapper assumes incompatible allocation implementations are compatible.

Comment: @paddy mixing different standard libraries, or standard libraries in different modes is a problem no matter what feature of the standard library you use. The question is about `std::malloc`/`free`, not about these general issues. You would run into the same issue if you used C++'s `std::malloc` and C++'s `std::free` but mixed standard libraries. That might also not work.

Comment: @paddy Mixing different implementations/flavours in the same executable is not well-defined even if the entirety of your program is in one language and no `malloc` is ever used. Your caveat can be attached to literally every single SO answer about C or C++.